# Having trouble when trying to implement a Event Handler for Windows API wrapper

Tags: c++, winapi, function, pointers, casting

Friends, I'm trying to implement a wrapper of Windows API, and I want to capture Child window events from the parent window, so I made a simple event handler. I used function pointers to store the callback functions. I did it with the static functions. See the code below.

```
class Widget;
typedef void (*EventProc)(MSG* EventArgs);
class Widget
{
public:
    /// Constructors destructor and methods for Registering and Creating Windows
    static LRESULT CALLBACK MainProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
    {
        MSG struct_msg;
        struct_msg.hWnd=hWnd;
        struct_msg.message=msg;
        struct_msg.wParam=wParam;
        struct_msg.lParam=lParam;

        Widget* wid=(Widget*)GetWidgetPointerFromHWND(hWnd);

        switch(msg)
        {
            case WM_CREATE:
                if(Created!=NULL)
                    (*(wid->Created))(&struct_msg);break;
            case WM_DESTROY:
                if(Destroyed!=NULL)
                    (*(wid->Destroyed))(&struct_msg);break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    EventProc Created;
    EventProc Destroyed;

};

class CustomControl: public Widget
{
    /// Constructor destructor and other methods

};

class Window: public Widget
{
public:

    static void ChildCreated(Widget* Sender,Widget* Self,MSG* EventArgs)
    {
        MessageBox(0,0,0,0);
    }

    Window()
    {
        control1=new CustomControl(100,100,200,200); //left,top,width,height
        this->AddChild(control1);
        control1->Created = ChildCreated; 
    }
private:
    CustomControl control1;
};
```

This works but since the static functions doesnt have this pointers, I was unable to access the variables and member functions in the **class Window**.
I want to make a member function as the callback function (Event Handler).
I hope you understand what I'm trying to solve. Please help me.

Comment: if you got instance of `Widget` from `GetWidgetPointerFromHWND`, you _do can_ access its variables and members. So what is wrong?

Comment: @Lol4t0 i want to make a non static member function of Window as event handler.

Comment: But as far as you get `wid`, you can call its function like `wid->handleEvent(msg, wParam, lParam)`. Right?

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of another GUI framework and see how they do it.

Comment: ok, my doubt is how can i make a non static member function as Event Handler and call it from the base class by its pointer. it is not just about this example@

Comment: Are you trying to reflect child-notifications normally sent to the parent forward to the child, child-level messages back up to the parent, or are you simply trying to find a general solution that can do *either*? Sorry, but the phrase "capture Child window events from the parent window" is a little nebulous for me.

Comment: And this code won't compile regardless. `control1` is declared as an member variable object, not an object *pointer*, yet you're assigning it `new CustomControl(100,100,200,200)` in the `Window()` constructor. Any chance we can see a closer facsimile of your *real* code?

Answer (score 1):

Your main idea you showed in this example is right.

You make some `static` `WndProc` function and mapping, that maps `HWND` to your classes.

When creating a new instance of widget, you add it to mapping. On destruction you remove it from mapping.

In your WndProc function you take instance of your class from mapping and call virtual Event Handler function of that instance:

```
class WidgetBase
{
public:
    WidgetBase()
    {
        _handle = CreateWindow(/*...*/, &WidgetBase::MainProc, /*...*/);
        _widgets.insert(std::make_pair(handle, this);
    }
    virtual ~WidgetsBase() 
    {
       _widgets.remove(handle);
    }
protected:
    HWND _handle;
    virtual LRESULT handleEvents(UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
    {
         return DefWindowProc(_handle, hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
    }
private:
    static std::map<HWND, WidgetBase*> _widgets;

    static WidgetBase* GetWidgetPointerFromHWND(HWND handle)
    {
        // some error handling should be put there
        return _widgets[handle];
    }

    static LRESULT CALLBACK MainProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
    {
        WidgetBase* wid=GetWidgetPointerFromHWND(hWnd);
        if (wid) {
            return wid->handleEvents(msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        else {
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
        }
    }
};
std::map<HWND, WidgetBase*> WidgetBase::_widgets;
```

Then in your derived class you have only to override `handleEvents` function:

```
class Derived: public WidgetBase
{
protected:
virtual LRESULT handleEvents(UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
    {
         // This is your event handler, that is memeber function
         //...
         return WidgetBase::handleEvents(msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};
```